# Does an external electric field change the potential of a conductor(which is isolated from ground and already given an amount of charge +Q)?

Tags: electrostatics

I was working out a problem from the standard text book of Electrodynamics of Professor David Jeffrey Griffiths. (Problem 3.20): 0Find the potential of a charged metal sphere(charge Q,radius R) placed in a otherwise uniform field E₀. Explain where you are setting the zero of potential?"
My Solution: I have assumed the potential due to external field is V₁ and potential due to induced charge is V₂ and the field is directed towards positive Z direction with center of the sphere at origine.
Now, ⁻∂V₁/∂z=E₀
so, V₁=-E₀z+c, now by setting potential due to electric field to be o at z=0(i.e xy plane or equitorial plane of the sphere), we get V₁=-E₀z. now switching to spherical polar coordinate V₁=-E₀rcosθ
now, V₂=Σ(Bₙ/rⁿ⁺¹)Pₙ(cosθ) for r≥R, where we are summing over all n∈N+{0}(Ihave taken Aₙ to be zero for r≥R,otherwise the potential due to induced charge would be diverging as r tends to infinite,and A₀=0 to set the potential to zero at r tends to infinite, due to induced charge)
so total potential, V=V₁+V₂
now I have to plugg in the boundary condition "at r=R, the total potential V=Q/4πε₀R,since it is a conductor" to get the right answer. i.e, (Q/4πε₀R)=-E₀Rcosθ+∑(Bₙ/Rⁿ⁺¹)Pₙ(cosθ),
using fourier trick, we get B₀=Q/4πε₀, and B₁=E₀R³ and the final resut is V=(-E₀rcosθ)+(E₀R³cosθ/r²)+(Q/4πε₀r).
But I'm not satisfied with the problm done, actually my intuition suggested me to assume total field V=Q/4πε₀R at r=R. But why? The conducting sphere was initially given a charge Q and due to that charge it got the potential Q/4πε₀R, but as soon I switch on the external uniform electric field, shouldn't the total potential(i.e, potential due to charge distribition and external field, the resultant potential)of the sphere be changed? Please answer.